# Increasing reliability of fetch requests

Tags: node.js, http, networking, fetch-api

I am building a service that needs to make thousands of network requests. The service is built with nodejs and uses the JavaScript Fetch API to make the requests.  These requests are all being made to a small set of endpoints. Reliability is more important than speed in making these requests.

I’m noticing that a number of these requests fail due to network timeouts. Which requests fail is random and is unrelated to the request details i.e. URL, headers or body.

I’m trying to figure out what I can do to improve the likelihood that all the requests succeed. Here are a couple things I have done

1. Reduce the number of concurrent requests
2. Set keepAlive to true
3. Increase timeout to 60000
4. Increase highWaterMark to 1,048,576

Is there anything else I should do to increase the likelihood of all requests succeeding?

Comment: This is entirely endpoint-specific.  If a given host you are sending a request to can only handle 10 simultaneous requests of the type you're sending without getting into really long delays, then the only way you can know that is through experimentation for each separate host to find out where it's threshold is for concurrent requests and back off from there.

Comment: Beyond that, you can lengthen your own timeout to however long seems useful and you can implement retry logic (while still staying below some threshold of simultaneous requests to the same host).  There's a good reason that browsers limit how many simultaneous requests they will allow to the same host to some pretty small number.

Comment: If reliability really is more important then speed, then perhaps only ever send two simultaneous requests to the same host.  Queue up the rest so they go in order, but the next one in the queue gets send only when a prior request finishes.  This is essentially what a browser does with multiple ajax calls to the same host.  That logic can all be hidden behind the request promise.